# Mantaflow not baking particles

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to Blender, and I'm trying to do the simplest fluid simulation possible in 2.82 using Mantaflow. I can't tell if I'm experiencing a bug, or not following the correct guidelines.

I'm using factory settings, everything is untouched except two meshes, a large domain cube (fluid physics->type: Domain [Domain Type: Liquid] & liquid option is checked) and a smaller fluid cube inside (fluid physics-> Flow Type: Liquid).

After baking, no particles are displayed throughout the timeline. The cache shows that it's certainly saved something, though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw this video a while ago that provides some fixes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O0QcLpAxV4&t=545s

Basically:

1. If you have a planar object, like a plane, it is bugged. In the flow object panel you have to increase the surface thickness from 0.5-1.
2. Make sure both object fluid modifiers, the domain one and the flow one, aren't hidden in the viewport or on the render when you bake fluid.
3. Make the Flow object bigger, but not bigger than the domain object and the flow object must be inside the domain object.

Those are some common problems, but without the file, I can't check what's wrong. Hope my answer helps, though!